# Looping over a data frame in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame and I'm trying to calculate median for each group separately. When I separate the data frame in two groups and calculate the median for each one, I am getting an `NA` result.

The data is :

```
    x1  x2  x3  x4  x5  x6  x7  y1  y2  y3  y4  y5  y6  y7  y8
9.488404158 9.470895414 9.282433728 9.366707445 9.955383045 9.640816474   9.606262272   9.329651027 9.434541611 9.473922432 9.311412966 9.3154885   9.434977488 9.470895414 9.764258059
8.630629966 8.55831075  8.788391003 8.576231135 8.671587906 8.842979993 8.861958856 8.58330436  8.603596508 8.570129609 8.59798922  8.572686772 8.679751791 8.663950953 8.432875347
9.354748885 9.367668838 9.259952558 9.421538213 9.554635162 9.603744578 9.452197983 9.284228877 9.404607878 9.317737979 9.343115301 9.310644266 9.27227486  9.360337823 9.44706281
9.944863964 9.950427516 10.19101759 10.07350804 10.03269879 10.1307908  10.03487287 9.74609383  9.886379007 9.775472567 10.036596   9.544738458 9.699611598 9.911962567 9.625804277
```

Code:

```
  rowN <- nrow(AT1)
  MD1<-vector(length=rowN)
  MD2<-vector(length=rowN)

   MD1[1:rowN]<-NA
   MD2[1:rowN]<-NA


 x<- AT1[,c(2,3,4,5,6,7,8) ]
  write.csv(x,"x.csv",row.names=TRUE)
  x<-as.matrix(x)
  for(i in 2:rowN) { 
  MD1[i]=median(x[i,])
  }
 write.csv(MD1,"MD1.csv",row.names=TRUE)

  y<- AT1[,c(9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16)]
  write.csv(y,"y.csv",row.names=TRUE)
  y<-as.matrix(y)
  for(j in 2:rowN) {
  MD2[j]=median(y[j,])
  }
  write.csv(MD2,"MD2.csv",row.names=TRUE)
```

Comment: Please show a reproducible example.  We can use `aggregate/dplyr/data.table` methods.

Comment: @akrun why the looping does not work , and R produce a extra column with index when i write csv file , and if i use median(x[,2:7]) , i will have error too :(

Comment: You were using `write.csv` with `row.names=TRUE`.  Use `row.names=FALSE` if you don't need that extra column.

Comment: I didn't find you creating the `MD1` and `MD2` object in the code.  I would do `MD1 <- numeric(nrow(x-1))` and same for `MD2` before the `for` loop step.

Comment: I have created MD1, MD2:                                                                            MD1<-vector(length=rowN)
MD2<-vector(length=rowN)

MD1[1:rowN]<-NA
MD2[1:rowN]<-NA

Comment: I showed some methods with a reproducible example.

Comment: your data as shown above only have 15 columns, but you're trying to select rows 9-16.  You should be getting an "undefined column" error.  Can you show the results of `str(AT1)` ?

Comment: I omit the first column , because its the ID 's

Comment: MD1 :x
NA
8.671588
9.421538
10.034873
10.387686
9.346154
7.936674
11.431484
10.984427   , R produce x, NA, then  median value for x group ?

Answer (score 3):

It would have been better to show a reproducible example.  Based on the loop code, it seems to me that the OP want to get the `median` of each row.  Assuming that the `median` is calculated for columns 2:8 and for 9:16 separately, we convert the 'data.frame' to 'matrix' (`as.matrix`) and use `rowMedians` from `library(matrixStats)`.

```
x1 <- as.matrix(AT1[2:8 ])
x2 <- as.matrix(AT1[9:16])

library(matrixStats)
rowMedians(x1, na.rm=TRUE)
#[1] -0.09411013 -0.08554095  0.11953107 -0.26869311  0.33224445

rowMedians(x2, na.rm=TRUE)
#[1]  0.10557881 -0.74135403 -0.05876725  0.69230776 -0.21402339
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
m1 <- matrix(rnorm(5*15), ncol=15)
AT1 <- data.frame(col1= LETTERS[1:5], m1)
```

Comment: the error produce in the second group (y ) and its : There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)

Comment: @shawinkarim  Without a reproducible example, I can't comment.  If I use some standard example, my code should work.

Comment: iam typing your name akrun  but its disappear  at the begging  ?

Comment: @shawinkarim that's because the author of a post is always notified, so starting the message with '@ their_name' is redundant when there's no other comment author :) Just the way SO works, but I agree it could be disturbing at first (Will delete this when I'll see a +1 on the comment meaning it's been read :p)

Comment: @shawinkarim, if you want more detailed answers, please include a reproducible example (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)) that clearly shows what is going wrong. The answer of @akrun nicely shows that you do not need a `for` loop to calculate the median per row of a matrix, and should also work on your data.